# Rails ActiveAdmin. How to set default value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, rubygems, activeadmin

I have code like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do

form do |f|
  f.inputs "Post Details" do
    f.input :title
    f.input :body
    f.input :published_at, :as => DateTime.now
  end
  f.actions
end
```

I want the field `:published_at` (which is t.datetime) to be set to the current date and time by default. My example doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yep. Found the answer myself.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do

form do |f|
  f.object.published_at = DateTime.now
  f.inputs "Post Details" do
    f.input :title
    f.input :body
    f.input :published_at
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the form is used for editing existing records as well as creating new ones, so it is preferable to use conditional assignment to avoid accidentally overwriting the existing value of `published_at` – ie. `f.object.published_at ||= DateTime.now`

Comment: `f.object.published_at = DateTime.now unless f.object.persisted?` assings default value only for new object. It will not overwrite empty value for existing object.

Answer (score 10):

You can try with something like this:

```
<%= f.input :published_at, input_html: {value: "#{Time.now}"} %>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. And at the same time it doesn't throw any errors. But why did you use erb syntax? This is the `post.rb` file in `app\admin` folder. And your variant throws an error of course. So I tried it like this: `f.input :published_at, input_html: {value: "#{DateTime.now}"}`. Changed `Time` to `DateTime` as well. And like this: `f.input :published_at, input_html: {value: DateTime.now}`

Comment: i've found the answer. See my comment.